# How to average vertically over a list containing a void list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, average, void

I have a list containing the following:

```
    list1 = [(4.974874129422414, 0.4384932775564907, 0.1879318517703546, 5.820735609514166, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2961961688603689, 0.21595885700786707, 5.848923022691187, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.28850876174946627, 0.18977362640233908, 5.826501216543082, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2887489932217097, 0.2176404773200905, 5.834028536994648, 1, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3005203353595069, 0.18961347208652674, 5.849643723630468, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.3235825566813912, 0.21515808543054254, 5.849964035159586, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.3520099475391594, 0.18937324061280378, 5.814569613228549, 0, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3860427394179732, 0.2174803230046498, 5.858131979266134, 1, 0), 
    (0.1506158961103403, 0.42768286128894817, 0.18969354924443318, 5.807843071967709, 0, 0)]
```

I need to have the average of these values over the vertical axes, such that the output looks like:

```
    [(average_col1, average_col2, average_col3, average_col4, average_col5, average_col6)]
```

However, the `np.mean(list1, axis=1)` command returns:

```
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thus I tried creating a numpy array using:

```
    a = np.array(list1)
    a = array([ (4.974874129422414, 0.4384932775564907, 0.1879318517703546, 5.820735609514166, 0, 0),
   (0.15069597326856923, 0.2961961688603689, 0.21595885700786707, 5.848923022691187, 1, 0),
   (0.15085612758502492, 0.28850876174946627, 0.18977362640233908, 5.826501216543082, 0, 0),
   (0.15069597326856923, 0.2887489932217097, 0.2176404773200905, 5.834028536994648, 1, 0),
   (0.15093620474325167, 0.3005203353595069, 0.18961347208652674, 5.849643723630468, 0, 0),
   (0.15069597326856923, 0.3235825566813912, 0.21515808543054254, 5.849964035159586, 1, 0),
   (0.15085612758502492, 0.3520099475391594, 0.18937324061280378, 5.814569613228549, 0, 0),
   (0.15093620474325167, 0.3860427394179732, 0.2174803230046498, 5.858131979266134, 1, 0),
   (0.1506158961103403, 0.42768286128894817, 0.18969354924443318, 5.807843071967709, 0, 0)], 
  dtype=[('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8'), ('col5', '<i4'), ('col6', '<i4')])
```

if I use the same averaging command as above it returns:

```
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thus I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: How about `np.mean(list,0)`?

Comment: use `np.mean(a, axis=0)`

Comment: You use `np.mean[list, axis=1]`, but it should be `np.mean(np.array(list), axis=1)`

Comment: Also, don't use a built-in, such as list, as a variable name. I can't reproduce your error, I'm guessing Thomas got it right. You do have the right axis though.

Comment: @ThomasKühn This still returns the same index error. I think it has something to do with the dtype differences of the columns.

Comment: Your declaration of `a` as an array is wrong in the second step in your example. You are declaring an array of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having with numpy is the declaration of the matrix in your example.

Given:

```
list1 = [(4.974874129422414, 0.4384932775564907, 0.1879318517703546, 5.820735609514166, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2961961688603689, 0.21595885700786707, 5.848923022691187, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.28850876174946627, 0.18977362640233908, 5.826501216543082, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2887489932217097, 0.2176404773200905, 5.834028536994648, 1, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3005203353595069, 0.18961347208652674, 5.849643723630468, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.3235825566813912, 0.21515808543054254, 5.849964035159586, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.3520099475391594, 0.18937324061280378, 5.814569613228549, 0, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3860427394179732, 0.2174803230046498, 5.858131979266134, 1, 0), 
    (0.1506158961103403, 0.42768286128894817, 0.18969354924443318, 5.807843071967709, 0, 0)]
```

You can easily use that to get the average by column in numpy:

```
>>> np.mean(list1, axis=0)
[ 0.68679585  0.34464285  0.20140261  5.83448231  0.44444444  0.        ]
```

You next have an interesting declaration:

```
a = np.array([ (4.974874129422414, 0.4384932775564907, 0.1879318517703546, 5.820735609514166, 0, 0),
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2961961688603689, 0.21595885700786707, 5.848923022691187, 1, 0),
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.28850876174946627, 0.18977362640233908, 5.826501216543082, 0, 0),
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2887489932217097, 0.2176404773200905, 5.834028536994648, 1, 0),
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3005203353595069, 0.18961347208652674, 5.849643723630468, 0, 0),
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.3235825566813912, 0.21515808543054254, 5.849964035159586, 1, 0),
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.3520099475391594, 0.18937324061280378, 5.814569613228549, 0, 0),
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3860427394179732, 0.2174803230046498, 5.858131979266134, 1, 0),
    (0.1506158961103403, 0.42768286128894817, 0.18969354924443318, 5.807843071967709, 0, 0)], 
  dtype=[('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8'), ('col5', '<i4'), ('col6', '<i4')])
```

That is not the same as `matrix=np.array(list1)` What it is doing is declaring a numpy [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) and naming each column and giving a dtype to that column

Each row element of that array is a tuple:

```
 >>> a[0]
 ( 4.97487413,  0.43849328,  0.18793185,  5.82073561, 0, 0)
```

And you cannot access columns in the usual way:

```
>>> a[:,0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Since it is actually a one dimensional array:

```
>>> a.shape
(9,)
```

Instead, you have to access columns by name:

```
>>> a['col1']
array([ 4.97487413,  0.15069597,  0.15085613,  0.15069597,  0.1509362 ,
        0.15069597,  0.15085613,  0.1509362 ,  0.1506159 ])
```

Or, to take the mean by column name:

```
>>> [np.mean(a[col]) for col in ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,7)]]
[0.68679584555500162, 0.34464284907500159, 0.20140260920884526, 5.8344823121106151, 0.44444444444444442, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for you first list without using numpy:

```
averages = [sum(i)/float(len(i)) for i in zip(*list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You used brackets (`[]`) instead of parentheses (`()`) when trying to call `np.mean`. This code should do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [(4.974874129422414, 0.4384932775564907, 0.1879318517703546, 5.820735609514166, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2961961688603689, 0.21595885700786707, 5.848923022691187, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.28850876174946627, 0.18977362640233908, 5.826501216543082, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.2887489932217097, 0.2176404773200905, 5.834028536994648, 1, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3005203353595069, 0.18961347208652674, 5.849643723630468, 0, 0), 
    (0.15069597326856923, 0.3235825566813912, 0.21515808543054254, 5.849964035159586, 1, 0), 
    (0.15085612758502492, 0.3520099475391594, 0.18937324061280378, 5.814569613228549, 0, 0), 
    (0.15093620474325167, 0.3860427394179732, 0.2174803230046498, 5.858131979266134, 1, 0), 
    (0.1506158961103403, 0.42768286128894817, 0.18969354924443318, 5.807843071967709, 0, 0)]

means = np.mean(np.array(list1),axis = 1)

print(means)
```

results in:

```
[ 1.90367248  1.25196234  1.07593996  1.248519    1.08178562  1.25656678
  1.08446815  1.26876521  1.09597256]
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to average over the columns, it's

```
means = np.mean(np.array(list1),axis = 0)
```

which gives:

```
[ 0.68679585  0.34464285  0.20140261  5.83448231  0.44444444  0.        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
list1 = np.array(list1)
mean_col = list1[:,col_index].mean()
```

Column_index stand for the index column that you want to compute the mean, i.e. index of column1 = 0 ,column2=1.

Tried on my own and it works:)